# NPM task with arguments being converted to strings

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to run NPM tasks with arguments creating some flexibilty in my NPM build setup.

These are my scripts

```
"styles": "node-sass",
"build:styles": "npm run styles -- --source-map false --output-style compressed --output ./public/styles ./build/styles",
"watch:styles": "npm run styles -- --source-map true --output-style nested --output ./public/styles ./build/styles --watch"
```

I run "npm run build:styles" which returns this:

```
node-sass "--source-map" "false" "--output-style" "compressed" "--output" "./public/styles" "./build/styles"
```

This is causing my sourcemaps to be created in a folder called "false" because of the setting to --source-map, when it really should be used as a boolean and not create those sourcemaps.

Any tips/ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question in general, but in this special case you could of course just replace the `npm run styles --` with a call to the `node-sass` binary directly...

Comment: Yes that is what I'm using at the moment. I Just recently discovered you could pass arguments, so thought I would optimize my build. But ran soon into trouble. :)

Answer (score 1):

Omit the `--source-map` option to get the behavior you want (no source maps).

I just ran into this myself, and as of node-sass v4.5.3, the `--source-map` option has counter-intuitive behavior:

1. The default, without the `--source-map` option, does not create source maps
2. `--source-map <directory-name>` creates source maps in the specified directory
3. `--source-map true` creates source maps in the css output directory (provided by the `-o`/`--output` option).  One might think `--source-map false` would behave consistently (as `false` certainly *seems* like a boolean), but no - it treats `false` as a directory name.

This happens even when calling the binary directly (at least on macOS, npm v5.3.0, node 8.2.1), it appears to be a logic error not an npm-related parsing error.